# Redirecting non-www to www on Google App Engine Flex

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, redirect

I have a custom domain configured with a Google App Engine Flex instance. I want the naked domain to be redirected to the www version.

Setting up a forward through the domain registrar does nothing.

And I understand that this needs to handled in app.yaml. Does the Flex environment even support URL handling? If it does, how can I achieve this? It's running a PHP application.

Answer (score 0):

A DNS CNAME can only help in eventually resolving the domain on which the request comes in, but it won't do redirection of requests coming in on one domain towards another domain.

In the flexible environment it is your app's responsability to decide what to do with an incoming request for certain domain. From [Requests and domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-routed#requests_and_domains):

> The domain name used for the request is included in the request data
>   that is passed to your app. Therefore, you can use the request data to
>   control how your app responds based on the domain name in the request.
>   For example, if you want to redirect to an official domain, you can
>   code your app to check the `Host` request header and then respond
>   accordingly based on the domain name.

How exactly you do that - it depends on your app's handler implementation. Check the documentation for the framework you use.

And, of course, you need to map both the naked domain and the `www` domain to your app.

Comment: There is no such thing as "DNS redirection."  DNS cannot cause HTTP pages or domains to redirect.   Maybe you mean "A DNS CNAME can only help..."?